# bash create command not found on CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos

I am not able to create a database. I get a bash create command not found error on entering fir example: create database rattic;
please help

CentOS version 6.5

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use MySQL.  You have to enter a MySQL prompt before creating a database.  [Here is a handy guide](http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/sql/MySQL_HowTo.html) for getting started with MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Bash is a system shell; not a DB shell. Assuming that you are using MySQL, you can get to a DB shell with the following command:

```
mysql -uroot -p
```

If you'd rather just use bash, it can be done but you still need to run the command through MySQL:

```
mysql -uroot -p -e "create database 'foo'"
```

For both of these commands, the -p option will tell it to ask you for a password. If you don't have one set on your root account (the default setup) then you don't need that.